# MySQL - Tricky Many2Many Query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, doctrine-orm

I have entities with multiple attributes with the following simplified schema:

Entity:

- id

Attribute:

- id
- name

entity_attribute:

- entity_id
- attribute_id

If I wanted to retrieve records having the attribute named 'male', I could write:

```
SELECT * FROM Entity
INNER JOIN entity_attribute ON ...
INNER JOIN Attribute ON ...
WHERE Attribute.name = 'male'
```

If I wanted to retrieve records having the attribute named 'male' or 'teacher', I could write:

```
SELECT * FROM Entity
INNER JOIN entity_attribute ON ...
INNER JOIN Attribute ON ...
WHERE Attribute.name = 'male'  OR Attribute.name = 'teacher'
```

If I wanted to retrieve records having the attribute named 'male' and having the attribute named 'teacher', I could write:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM Entity
INNER JOIN entity_attribute ON ...
INNER JOIN Attribute ON ...
WHERE Attribute.name = 'male'  OR Attribute.name = 'teacher'
HAVING cnt = 2
```

Now comes the tricky part. My query needs to contain `and` and `or` combined in the manytomany query.

#### Example:

Which are those entities which [(have the attribute 'male') and (have the attribute 'teacher' or have the attribute 'gardener') and (have the attribute 'likes_apple' or have the attribute 'likes_orange' or have the attribute 'likes_cherry')].

Working with subqueries could be a solution, however as far as I know, that would be slow(~10000 Entities, ~30 Attributes, ~15000 entity_attributes). What could be a fast solution?

Answer (score 0):

well u can do 3 queries and a union on them, that would be the fastest(easiest) way

if you want a fast way...use exists with a sub query, the idea of exists is that it returns true on the first item that matches...so you would avoid this way a inner join and a multiple where clausal

Comment: Could you be more specific? What would those 3 queries be with the union?

Comment: i will have more time tomorrow, then I'll answer your question with examples